# How to run pytest Gitlab CI job while using dockerized microservices and postgres?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pytest, gitlab-ci

Working on project with multiple dockerized parts.
Three of them (db, celery, worker) required for pytests to pass.
How should I approach this task?

I want that containers up so I can run pytest normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitLab CI services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) to run Docker containers in parallel to your CI job. The yml will look something like the following:

```
job:
  services:
    - postgres:11.7
  image: python:3.10
  script:
    - pytest
```

Comment: Ok. That is Postgress. What about other containers? with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: Well you can add any container you want, also from a private Docker registry. Since GitLab itself can act as a Docker registry I'd suggest to use it, since it makes authentication quite easy.
Build the containers you need in a previous step, push them to the docker-registry using the branch name as the tag for example and then use them as services.